# scaling axhline to data

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, line, transform

I want to extend an hline from from the y-axis to my data. However, the origin of the subplot is not 0,0. So when I specify the x-value of my data for xmax of the hline, I get:

```
hln = ax.axhline(0.5,xmax=0.07,zorder=5,c='#cccccc')
```

[image: hline without offset]

When I offset the hline with the xlims, I get close:

```
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
hln = ax.axhline(0.5,xmin=xlim[0],xmax=0.07+abs(xlim[0]),zorder=5,c='#cccccc')
```

[image: hline with xlim min as offset for axhline xmax]

However, I've got a bunch of subplots and multiple lines/subplot so I want to be calling the value for xmax from my data source. While I can mostly get there using the above, the documentation for [axhline](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) suggests a transform kwarg can be called. This would seem the simplest approach, but I can't seemed to figure out the implementation. When I try:

```
 hln = ax.axhline(0.5,xmin=xlim[0],xmax=0.07+abs(xlim[0]),zorder=5,c='#cccccc',kwargs={'transform':ecdf_z_indiv})
```

I get:

> AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'kwargs'

in the above case, ecdf_z_indiv is an statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF object, though I have also tried an array of the x values. However, that seems immaterial for the present error.

Cheers

Comment: What about hlines, instead? You can say ```ax.hlines(0.5, xmin=xlim[0], xmax=0.07, transform=ax.transData)```. Does this solve you problem?

Comment: not quite, but thank-you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

here's an answer, but it's not THE answer I was looking for.

This works:

```
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
xlim_rng = xlim[1]-xlim[0]
ax.axhline(0.5, xmin=xlim[0], xmax=(0.07/xlim_rng)-xlim[0]/xlim_rng)
```

[image]

I'm still interested in a solution with transform if anyone has suggestions. I suspect it will be far less verbose.

Cheers